# Error while connecting to PayPal with API for transaction

Tags: api, paypal, transactions

I am getting the following error while trying to connect PayPal with transaction details using an API:

```
Type    PPConnectionException
Message     error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure 
Detail  Error connecting to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
```

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article about the [POODLE Vulnerability](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).

That post is specific to PHP environments, but the basic problem is that your server software stack needs to be able to send the POST requests to PayPal over the TLS 1.2 protocol instead of SSL.